# "Percentage" alternatives to MAPE

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, model-evaluation, rms, mape

I'm aware of the problems of MAPE as a measurement, and particularly it's uselessness in the event of a time series where 0 is one of the many values of *y*.

The downside to ditching MAPE in favour of something like RMSE is that that measurement is less comparable where the 'scale' of the y values involved changes. For example with MAPE I can look at model A, where sum(y) = 1000 and model B where sum(y) = 1000000 and say they're comparable when MAPE = 0.1 for both. With RMSE, an error of 100 for A vs 100000 for B makes it less clear.

What alternative evaluation metrics retain that comparability, but don't have the same problems as MAPE (particularly the inability to handle y=0)? My instinct is something like RMSE / mean of y, but I'm not certain whether that's particularly valid.

EDIT: Turns out yes, it is. It's called [*normalised root mean square error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation#Normalized_root-mean-square_deviation). I'd love to hear of any others though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look into scaled versions of the MAE and RMSE, namely the MASE and RMSSE proposed by [Hyndman and Koehler (2006)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207006000239). Besides being scale-invariant they behave well when $y=0$ and are symmetric (that is, penalizing positive and negative errors equally). 
Furthermore, these metrics are asymptotically normal (see [Franses (2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207015000448)) so that they can be used within a testing setup if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Although very intuitive and was preferred commonly (me, too), the only problem you may face with MAPE is not just the case where $y=0$. Especically when the predicted series is positive, e.g. CLTV, when $\hat{y}<y$, (an *underestimate*), the percentage error cannot be greater than $1$. In overestimates, $\hat{y}>2y$ guarantees a MAPE with larger than $1$. So, it implicitly favours for *underestimates*. To deal with such issues, sometimes we can resort to [SMAPE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error) (which was proposed by [Makridakis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0169207093900793?via%3Dihub), or by [Armstrong](http://www.forecastingprinciples.com/files/LRF-Ch13b.pdf) with the name *adjusted MAPE*), in which we take the average (sometimes sum) of $y$ and $\hat{y}$ for the denominator.